# How to add elliptic curve points in python?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, elliptic-curve

I'm trying to implement a simple elliptic curve encryption program but I can't get the expected output of doubling and adding a Point `P` till `12P` .The curve equation is`y^2 = x^3 +ax + b mod p`. According to this [site](http://www.christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx) `3P = [10, 6]` when `P = [5, 1]` while I get `3p = [10, 5]`. The equations I use can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Point_addition).

```
P = [5, 1]
prime = 17
a = 2
b = 2

def gcdExtended(a, b):
     if a == 0:
          return b, 0, 1
     gcd, x1, y1 = gcdExtended(b % a, a)
     x = y1 - (b // a) * x1
     y = x1
     return gcd, x, y

def double_point(point: list):
     x = point[0]
     y = point[1]

     s = ((3*(x**2)+a) * (gcdExtended(2*y, prime)[1])) % prime

     newx = (s**2 - x - x) % prime
     newy = (s * (x - newx) - y) % prime

     return [newx, newy]

def add_points(P: list, Q: list):
     x1 = P[0]
     y1 = P[1]
     x2 = Q[0]
     y2 = Q[1]

     s = ((y2 - y1) * ((gcdExtended(x2-x1, prime))[1] % prime)) % prime

     newx = (s**2 - x1 - x2) % prime
     newy = (s * (x1 - newx) - y1) % prime

     return [newx, newy]

Q = P
index = 2
while True:
     if Q[0] == P[0] and Q[1] == P[1]:
          print("doubling")
          Q = double_point(P)
     else:
          print("adding")
          Q = add_points(Q, P)

     if index == 12 :
          break

     print(f"{index}P = {Q}")
     index += 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the point `[5,1]` is added successively, the following sequence is obtained:

```
 1P = [ 5,  1]          
 2P = [ 6,  3]
 3P = [10,  6]
 4P = [ 3,  1]
 5P = [ 9, 16]
 6P = [16, 13]
 7P = [ 0,  6]
 8P = [13,  7]
 9P = [ 7,  6]
10P = [ 7, 11]
11P = [13, 10]
12P = [ 0, 11]
13P = [16,  4]
14P = [ 9,  1]
15P = [ 3, 16]
16P = [10, 11]
17P = [ 6, 14]
18P = [ 5, 16]
19P = point at infinity
```

This can be verified e.g. [here](https://graui.de/code/elliptic2/).

The problem in the posted code is that the method to determine the modular inverse, `gcdExtended(a, b)`, is only valid for positive `a` and `b`. While in `double_point` and `add_points` `b` has the value `prime` (`= 17 > 0`), `a` can take negative values.

`gcdExtended` generally returns wrong values for negative `a`:

- The modular inverse of 5 or -12 is 7: 5 x 7 mod17 = 35 mod17 = 1 and 7 x (-12) mod17 = -84 mod17 = 85 mod17 = 1.
- The `gcdExtended` returns for these values: `gcdExtended(5, 17)[1] = 7` (which is true) and `gcdExtended(-12, 17)[1] = -7` (which is false).

To allow negative values for `a`, e.g. the following methods can be defined, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/37811):

```
def sign(x): 
    return 1 if x >= 0 else -1

def gcdExtendedGeneralized(a, b):
    gcd, x1, y1 = gcdExtended(abs(a), b)
    return gcd, (sign(a) * x1) % b, y1 % b
```

Replacing `gcdExtended` with `gcdExtendedGeneralized` in `double_point` and `add_points` provides the correct values (note that the current implementation does not consider the point at infinity).

Answer (score 1):

You interchanged `P` and `Q` in `add_points`. Also a small simplification in your calculation of s:

```
def add_points(P: list, Q: list):
    x1 = P[0]
    y1 = P[1]
    x2 = Q[0]
    y2 = Q[1]

    #s = ((y2 - y1) * ((gcdExtended(x2-x1, prime))[1] % prime)) % prime
    s = (y2-y1) * (gcdExtended(x2-x1, prime)[1] % prime)

    newx = (s**2 - x1 - x2) % prime
    newy = (s * (x1 - newx) - y1) % prime

    return [newx, newy]

Q = P
index = 2
while True:
    if Q[0] == P[0] and Q[1] == P[1]:
        print("doubling")
        Q = double_point(P)
    else:
        print("adding")
        Q = add_points(P, Q)

    if index == 12 :
        break

    print(f"{index}P = {Q}")
    index += 1
```

which results in

```
doubling
2P = [6, 3]
adding
3P = [10, 6]
adding
4P = [3, 1]
adding
5P = [9, 16]
adding
6P = [16, 13]
adding
7P = [0, 6]
adding
8P = [13, 8]
adding
9P = [8, 7]
adding
10P = [8, 10]
adding
11P = [13, 9]
adding
```

Comment: Actually, point addition should be [commutative](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/in-ecc-how-do-i-prove-that-point-addition-is-commutative), so swapping `P` and `Q` in `add_points(P, Q)` should have no effect.